# How upload multiple photos at the same time?? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a problem with upload photos.

In muy view, i take some photo as below:

```
<%= f.label :images_urls, 'image' %> <br>
    <%= f.file_field :images_urls, {:multiple => true} %> <br>
```

But I don't know how save them in controller to my model "Furniture".
This is my furniture, but i don't work:

```
 def create
    image_io = params[:furniture][:images_urls]
    File.open(Rails.root.join('public','furnitures', image_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
      file.write(image_io.read)
    end

    @furniture = Furniture.create(params[:furniture])

    redirect_to admins_path
  end
```

Have you any suggestion??

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a gem such as [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) or [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). In your view, to allow multiple file upload, you may need to implement asynchronous file upload. A very handy way to do this that uses jQuery is a plugin called jQuery-file-upload (which can handle multiple files).

Ryan Bates has an excellent video on Railscasts [jQuery File Upload](http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload) on how to do this. There's also a gem that prepackages this jQuery plugin for you, called [jquery-fileupload-rails](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails).

Comment: The video I suggested in my answer, on Railscasts ([jQuery File Upload](http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload)) is a great tutorial. It's the one I used to learn about this. On the Railscasts site, there are many free videos. If you are looking to get some good practical experience with Rails, this is one of the best places to start.